# Azure service message - Some messages are getting deleted but not received

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am reading messages continuously. But this code is not reading all the messages even if queue is getting empty, But messages are not read.

Read messages in while loop.

```
var serviceBusHelper = new ServiceBusMessageHelper();    
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
             var timeToPollMessage = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
             messages = await serviceBusHelper.ReadMessagesAsync(queueName, 10);
             var elapsedTimeToPollMessageMs = timeToPollMessage.ElapsedMilliseconds;
             AppLogger.LogError("**** Elapsed to Poll message batch in ms " + elapsedTimeToPollMessageMs + " ****");
    
      }
   }
    
    
        class ServiceBusMessageHelper
        { 
            static string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxxxxxx";
            static ServiceBusClient serviceBusuClient  = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    
            public async Task<IReadOnlyList<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>> ReadMessagesAsync(string queueName, int batchSize)
            {
                var receiverOptions = new ServiceBusReceiverOptions()
                {
                    ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete,
                };
                var receiver = serviceBusuClient.CreateReceiver(queueName, receiverOptions);
                //await receiver.CompleteMessageAsync
                return await receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(batchSize);
            }
        }
```

Solution -  I have rearranged code as suggested by sean.

```
var serviceBusHelper = new ServiceBusMessageHelper();
            string connectionString = "Endpoint=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
            var receiverOptions = new ServiceBusReceiverOptions()
            {
                ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock,
            };

            var receiver = serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(queueName, receiverOptions);
            int batchSize = 10;

            while (true)
            {
                var timeToCollect100Books = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                IReadOnlyList<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> messages = null;

                try
                {
                    BackToPollMessage:
                    var timeToPollMessage = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    messages = await receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(batchSize);
                    AppLogger.LogError("Received Messages : " + messages.Count());
                    var elapsedTimeToPollMessageMs = timeToPollMessage.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    AppLogger.LogError("**** Elapsed to Poll message batch in ms " + elapsedTimeToPollMessageMs + " ****");
                    foreach (var repricedMessage in messages)
                    {
                        await receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(repricedMessage);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
```

It is solving issue to read all messages but now a new problem arises where outgoing message is way more than incoming messages now. Even though I have only one instance of this consumer running

[image]

Queue Config
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running in a risky `ReceiveAndDelete` mode. It means that the moment a message is requested from the broker and delivered to the client, it will be immediately removed from the broker, regardless of whether it was processed successfully by the client. Unless this is your intention, I suggest you switch to `PeekLock` mode and complete incoming messages once you've processed those.

Also, this code is continuously creating message receivers for each iteration of the loop. Highly recommend reviewing what you're trying to achieve and how it's implemented.

Comment: Can you please explain why creating receiver every time is bad?

Comment: It's not necessarily bad just doesn't do anything useful. Every receiver created from the same Service Bus client shares the same connection object to the broker. By creating multiple of those senders, you're not establishing multiple connections and increasing throughput. So why to create a receiver each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Sean Thanks for clarification. I improved the code as you suggested but now I am observing outgoing messages are way more than incoming. So I am doubting that program is reading it again before deleting

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/316

Comment: Yes I checked this thread no resolution yet.  I talked  to azure support - We observed that there were increase in try receive messages, so generally this try receive messages are the messages when the receiver is not available to consume those messages then those messages will stay in the active queue until the TTL that you have set. Before the TTL expires and the delivery failed messages which are staying in the active queue, once the receiver is ready to consume the message, service bus will retry sending those delivery failed messages to receiver along with the active incoming messages.

Comment: After their response I tried to sleep thread after receiving each message but no benefit. Can you draw something after reading this?